# « Le livre à Sébastien » ou « le livre de Sébastien » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, possessif

Je voudrais bien savoir dans quelle situation on doit utiliser « à » et dans laquelle on doit utiliser « de ».

D'un autre côté, c'est quoi la différence entre « à » et « de » dans les phrases suivantes:

> Le livre à Sébastien
>
> Le livre de Sébastien

Comment: Est-ce que Sébastien est la personne qui possède le livre, ou alors est-il l'auteur du livre ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le possessif en français s'exprime avec *de*. L'exemple « le livre à Sébastien » se rencontre à l'oral mais est grammaticalement incorrect. On parle du « livre **de** Sébastien ».

Il existe toutefois un cas où l'on utilise *à* pour exprimer la possession : lorsque l'on répond à la question « À qui appartient ce livre ? » On dira alors « C'est **à** Sébastien. » ou « C'est le livre de Sébastien. »

À noter : « C'est **de** Sébastien. » est grammaticalement correct mais a une autre signification : soit c'est **de la part de** Sébastien (c'est lui qui offre ce livre), soit Sébastien est l'auteur du livre.

Answer (score 3):

[L'académie a répondu à cette question.](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#1_strong-em--la-voiture-de-julie-ou-la-voiture--julie-em-strong)

> La préposition "**à**" marque normalement l’appartenance après un verbe (cette maison est, appartient à notre ami). On l’emploie avec la même valeur devant un pronom, seule (un ami à nous) ou pour reprendre un possessif (c’est sa manière à lui). Mais on ne peut plus l’employer entre deux noms, comme on le faisait dans l’ancienne langue, sauf dans des locutions figées (une bête à Bon Dieu), par archaïsme ou dans un usage très familier. On dira : la voiture de Julie, les fleurs de ma mère.

Answer (score 1):

L'expression exprimant correctement à qui appartient le livre est:

> Le livre de Sébastien

On utilisera cependant « à » s'il ne s'agit pas de préciser l'appartenance mais le destinataire :

> Rends le livre de Sébastien (= rends son livre)
>
> Rends le livre à Sébastien (= rends lui le livre)